# Accessing the subscription/num_oustanding_messages metric in Google PubSub from Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-python, google-cloud-monitoring

Is it possible to access the `subscription/num_outstanding_messages` metric listed https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#gcp-pubsub from google-cloud-python? I've used similar code to successfully access the `num_undelivered_messages` metric, but iterating over the results of the following query (which succeeds) always yields an empty list.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.cloud import monitoring
>>> client = monitoring.Client()
>>> q = client.query(
...     "pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages",
...     minutes=90
... )
>>> len(list(q)) > 0
True
>>> q = client.query(
...     "pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_outstanding_messages",
...     minutes=90
... )
>>> len(list(q)) > 0
False
```

Relevant google-cloud-python library versions:

```
~:pip freeze | grep google
gapic-google-logging-v2==0.10.1
gapic-google-pubsub-v1==0.10.1
google-cloud==0.21.0
google-cloud-bigquery==0.21.0
google-cloud-bigtable==0.21.0
google-cloud-core==0.21.0
google-cloud-datastore==0.21.0
google-cloud-dns==0.21.0
google-cloud-error-reporting==0.21.0
google-cloud-happybase==0.20.0
google-cloud-language==0.21.0
google-cloud-logging==0.21.0
google-cloud-monitoring==0.21.0
google-cloud-pubsub==0.21.0
google-cloud-resource-manager==0.21.0
google-cloud-runtimeconfig==0.21.0
google-cloud-storage==0.21.0
google-cloud-translate==0.21.0
google-cloud-vision==0.21.0
google-gax==0.14.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.10.1
grpc-google-logging-v2==0.10.1
grpc-google-pubsub-v1==0.10.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `num_outstanding_messages`, which represents the number of messages sent to a subscriber that have not yet been acknowledged, is only available for push subscribers. Note that although the API does not make this distinction explicit, in [Stackdriver](https://app.google.stackdriver.com), the metric shows up as "push outstanding messages." The [Subscriber Guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push_pull) talks about the difference between a push subscriber and a pull subscriber.